# Determine if a improper integral converge using some criterion

Tags: improper-integrals

There is a criterion to decide if the following integral converge or not?

$$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \left(\dfrac12\right)^x\sin x\,dx$$

The idea is to avoid calculating its value.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{+\infty}2^{-x}\,dx = \frac{1}{\log 2}$ is convergent, so...

Comment: Thanks @JackD'Aurizio  but $sin(x)$ is not a positive function, can I to use the  comparison test in this case?

Comment: The value of the integral between $\int (-2^{-x})\; dx$ and $\int 2^{-x}\; dx$ both of which are finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

$$|(\frac 12)^x\sin(x)|\le e^{-x\ln(2)}$$

By comparison test, the integral is absolutely convergent.